# How can I filter traffic using a layer 3 switch?

Tags: windows, cisco, switch, vlan, route

I have a layer 3 switch which needs to route traffic to 2 different networks which don't see each other.

What would be the simplest and most efficient way to do this? And is there any straight forward documentation I could follow to get this done?

Comment: Wow.  Complete lack of effort here.  How about the make/model of the switch for starters?

Comment: Your question title refers to filtering traffic while the actual question refers to routing traffic. Which is it? I'm assuming you're referring to routing traffic between these 2 networks, right?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. 

I am using a Cisco Catalyst 3560 switch, all the traffic that comes through the internet will reach this switch.

Once it reaches the switch, the switch needs to determine where to send the traffic to. Certain IP's are only allowed to network 1, and other IP's are only allowed to go to network 2. 

What would be the best and efficient way to get this set up? 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Q. What would be the simplest and most efficient way to do this?

A. Routing

Q.  Is there any straight forward documentation I could follow to get this done?

A. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/exploring-tcpip-routers.html